# Using gerund vs. relative pronoun in sentences: "A set S that consists of x, y, z is called.." vs "A set S consisting of x, y, z is called..."

Tags: gerunds, relative-clauses, writing, reduced-relative-clauses, compounds

I saw many sentences with the following pattern:

> A set **S** consisting of x, y, z is called...,

which uses the gerund form of the verb "consist".

Considering another sentence that I created based on the sentence above with equivalent meaning:

> A set **S** that consists of x, y, z is called...,

which uses the relative pronoun "that" instead.

For me both are the same but I'm not sure if there's any difference or not. If yes, can someone help provide me with some writing guideline on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A set S consisting of x, y, z is called...,

> A set S that consists of x, y, z is called...,

Your suggested version means the same as the original one.   *that* is called a relativiser.  Instead of that, we can also use the relative pronoun **which**.

In the original version, the relative clause has been reduced to a gerund-participial clause.  *consisting* in traditional grammar was called present participle but is now called gerund-participle.